# How to get the value of TextBox (programmatically added) which is inside a user control (user control rendered inside Repeater)

Tags: asp.net, webusercontrol

Generally we do this to get the value of textbox which is inside a user control.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" Text="Test" ID="txtTest"/>
```

In code behind create a property

```
public string MyString
  {  
     get  { return txtTest.Text; }   
  }
```

And in parent page we can get the instance of user control and get the value of textbox like

```
foreach (RepeaterItem itm in rptAttribute.Items)
{     
 MyUserControl uc = ((MyUserControlitemUserControl)itm.FindControl("MyContorlName"));
 string  test = uc.MyString;
}
```

but not sure How to render the value if the Textbox in user control created Programmatically.

Comment: are you able to determine the ID of the textbox that you'll be looking for and are you creating the dynamic textboxes during the Page_Init event handler?

Comment: i gave the id pragmatically while declaring textbox in page_init method.

Comment: Basically, you have dynamically created MyUserControls inside Repeater and a dynamically created TextBox inside MyUserControl. If so, how do you create TextBox dynamically inside UserControl?

Comment: @Win: I didn't created user control dynamically. just textbox is dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a similar approach to your text box but declare a public method which takes the textbox name as a parameter and then returns it like this:

In your ASCX:

```
public TextBox GetDynamicTextBoxByID(string textBoxId)
{
  return (TextBox)Page.FindControl(textBoxId);
}
```

In your Parent page:

```
foreach (RepeaterItem itm in rptAttribute.Items)
{     
 MyUserControl uc = ((MyUserControlitemUserControl)itm.FindControl("MyContorlName"));
 string  test = uc.MyString;
 TextBox tx = uc.GetDynamicTextBoxByID(idOfTextBox);
}
```

Don't forget to check for null being returned and handling appropriately.

Comment: TextBox tx = uc.GetDynamicTextBoxByID(idOfTextBox);  works for name of the control but it's not working with the ID of control.

Comment: Hmmm interesting - could you post your working code (add it into your question)? Thanks for the accept anyway tho! To be honest you'd done all the hard part already ;o)